# Problems adding Kali Linux to VirtualBox

Tags: bios, kali-linux, vt-x

I downloaded Kali Linux on Windows 10 on a 64-bit Gateway laptop. I also downloaded VirtualBox so I could dual boot, but after downloading everything, first of all it only shows 32-bit options when creating a new guest OS in VirtualBox, and it doesn’t show Kali in order to add it. I tried to do an advanced boot to make sure virtualization was enabled in the BIOS, but there’s no menu to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Enable Intel VT-X Virtualization on PC

There are two ways to enable Virtualization technology on a PC.

- UEFI firmware
- BIOS

---

1. Go to *Settings* -> *UPDATE & SECURITY* -> *Recovery* and click the *Restart now* button under *Advanced start-up*.

   [image: Settings]
    <sup>**Settings**</sup>
2. While restarting your computer, choose *Troubleshoot* -> *Advanced options* -> *UEFI Firmware settings* -> click *Restart*.

   If you don't have the *UEFI Firmware Settings* option in *Advanced options* then no problem, you'll find the VT-x virtualization option in the BIOS or boot menu.

   [image: UEFI Firmware Settings]
    <sup>**UEFI Firmware Settings**</sup>
3. On the boot menu, navigate to *Advanced options/Configuration*, find Intel Virtual Technology and enable it by pressing the <kbd>F6</kbd> key.

   [image: Boot menu]
   <sup>**Boot menu**</sup>
4. To the enable VT-X from BIOS, power on or restart your computer if it's powered on and while restarting when the first page appears press the BIOS key to enter into BIOS setup utility. Select *BIOS Setup* and on the BIOS setup page select System configuration and you'll find the Virtualization Technology option. Press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key to toggle Disable/Enable.

   BIOS Keys:

```
    Manufacturer    BIOS/UEFI key
    Acer            Del, F2
    ASUS            F9
    Compaq          F10
    Dell            F2
    Gateway         Tab, Del
    HP              Esc, F10, F1
    Intel           F10
    Lenovo          F1, F2
    Samsung         F2
    Toshiba         F1, F2, F3
    Sony            F1, Esc, F12
    Packard Bell    F1, Del
    NEC             F2
```

[image: Enable virtualization (Intel VT-X) in BIOS - Lenovo]
            <sup>**Enable virtualization (Intel VT-X) in BIOS - Lenovo**</sup>

<sub>**Source:** [How to Enable Intel VT-X & AMD Virtualization on a PC](https://www.tactig.com/enable-intel-vt-x-amd-virtualization-pc-vmware-virtualbox/)</sub>